# App Script On Edit trigger delays before firing script (from google sheet)

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

Using an On Edit trigger on my App Script in a Google Sheet always takes a second or more to execute the action. Even something simple like the following can take anywhere from 1/4 to 1/2 second.

```
function onEdit(e){

  Logger.log("Time test");

}
```

So there is a delay between when I edit a cell and when the onEdit function is triggered.
If the edit is triggered from a datavalidation dropdown, this can be up to a second lag just to start the onEdit function, regardless of what else I'm doing in there.

Is there any way to speed up this lag, or is it just something I have to live with?

Thanks

I've done numerous tests, and even the simplest onEdit function call (like in my code snippet above) still has a delay. I found one existing question on this topic but it was older and only had one answer (that said this lag is unavoidable) but I was hoping for a different answer lol.

Comment: Since your `onEdit(e)` simply logs a message to the execution log.  There may not be a delay in `onEdit` but there can be a delay in the time it takes the execution log to display the message.  It would be better to simply log a start time and end time and see the difference.

Comment: I've always found that you have to be patient with onEdit most of the time it's very slow.  If the operation it's performing is trivial then it's probably not worth doing in an onEdit in my book.

Comment: @TheWizEd that was just a junk function to show that even on the simplest code, I was still seeing a delay. I did a number of tests, all with varying degrees of complexity, and nothing ever fired in under 1/4 second. Even simple functions like this generally take about 0.4 to 0.5 seconds to complete. In fact, this exact function itself takes varying time amounts to complete.

Comment: Sheet size. If the sheet is bulky, the time is unavoidable. Try in a new empty sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the absolute best performance out of your onEdit() then you should begin the onEdit the way doubleUnary and Tanaike do and that is to begin with a conditional branch that directs the edits from anything other than the range of interest too a return as fast as possible.  Personally, I hate using the reverse logic and so I avoid doing this. But it is probably the most efficient.  After saying that I still find the onEdit to be much less than satisfying when compared to the kind of performance you can get with Excel and a pc but I'm willing to forgo that performance to have a complete set of tools that allows me to build my own custom functions for 12 dollars a month and I'm willing to tolerate having to share it with possibly billions of people.

- [Some of doubleunary's onEdit answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A13045193+%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+onEdit)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very simple `onEdit(e)`.  As you can see it takes 2 milliseconds.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  try {
    let time1 = new Date();
    Logger.log("Time test")
    let time2 = new Date();
    time1 = time2.valueOf()-time1.valueOf();
    Logger.log(time1+(" milliseconds"));
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().toast(err);
  }
}
```

Execution log

```
Oct 26, 2023, 5:41:25 PM    Info    Time test
Oct 26, 2023, 5:41:25 PM    Info    2 milliseconds
```